# Windows 10 EFI boot files get deleted every few days in dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 installed in a dual-boot GPT/UEFI setup, I use grub2 to boot into Windows and Ubuntu.

I tried `boot-repair` on Ubuntu, it gives the error:

```
LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware.
```

I searched everywhere but was unable to find a solution.
Recently, when I use Ubuntu more often, the Windows EFI boot files get deleted randomly once a few days and I have to repair it with a bootable Windows USB drive, and it keeps happening.

Comment: You have legacy Windows and UEFI Ubuntu?

Comment: You really cannot have legacy Windows & UEFI Ubuntu. Windows in BIOS mode has to be MBR with boot flag on primary NTFS partition with boot flag. UEFI requires boot/esp flags on ESP - efi system partition. If UEFI system with UEFI Windows you must always boot in UEFI mode. If BIOS/MBR you must always boot in BIOS mode. Post this: `sudo parted -l`